# How to determine order of TestSet TestCases with Rally RestApi Request

Tags: rally

I am trying to retrieve/determine the order of TestCases within a Rally TestSet using the following:

```
Request requestTC = new Request(test_set["TestCases"]);
findTCMatchQueryResult = m.myRestApi.Query(requestTC);
```

However, regardless of whether or not I specify an "Order" of "DragAndDropRank" or do not specify an "Order", I can never retrieve the order of TestSet TestCases that I see in Rally.

For example,

In the Rally website, I have a TestSet with TestCases "X", "Y", and "Z" in that order, but with the above code, I can never seem to get the test cases in that order.

How can I find the order that is shown in the Rally website?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these TCs sorted by FormattedID, Name or something else? Apply sorting function then.

Comment: The TCs are not sorted by FormattedID, Name, or anything else.  They're ordered manually in the web interface by dragging & dropping them into the correct order.

Comment: Then, sort by `Rank` in your query request.

Comment: @user2738882, I assume you're referring to the following:

`request.Order = "Rank";`

If so, this still does not yield the same result as the order shown on the Rally website.  My assumption is that the test cases have an order amongst all test cases, and this is the order you get when you specify "DragAndDropRank" in a TestSet["TestCases"] request, NOT the rank as shown in the website... is that a correct assumption?

Comment: The easiest way to say for sure the following: 1. Open your TestSet in browser. 2. Open DevTools in your browser and go to Network tab (make sure Preserve Logs option is set) 3. Refresh the page. 4. Look into network request for something like `Request URL: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.x/workspace?compact=true&includePermissions=true&fetch=Name%2CObjectID&order=Name&pagesize=200&query=(State%20%3D%20%22Open%22)&workspace=null` 5. order=Name (or something other in your case) will be your answer. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Rank" of things is specified by the DragAndDropRank field. The thing to remember is that DragAndDropRank is specific to the context. For example, if I move TestCases about under the test set in the Iteration Status page, the DragAndDropRank is set for that. If I move TestCases around in the Quality->TestCases page, this is a different context and therefore the "rank" is different. However, they *should* remain consistent in that if you move TC6 above TC5 in the TestCases page (against other TestCases), then that should be reflected in the Iteration Status page where TC6 and TC5 are under TS2.

The DragAndDropRank field on artefacts is not a number, it is a long hash value encoded with the info needed for both cases.